# how to limit the V8 heap usage for node & npm system wide?

Tags: node.js, memory, npm, webpack

I have an npm run script which in turn runs `webpack` to build code on the server. But I have only 512 MB RAM on this machine and the RAM is a constraint so can't upgrade that.

Webpack build breaks at around 80% completion. The process gets killed. And I know its because of memory because it completes successfully if I stop all the other processes that are taking up significant memory.

Having said that, I want to limit the V8 heap limit of `node` & the `node` used by `npm` to say 128 MB or something.

So my questions are.

1. How do you verify that V8's heap is capped indeed? I tried `process.memoryUsage()` but everytime `heapTotal` was same.
2. How to make sure node only uses 128 MB heap when ran from anywhere in the system. I tried adding the below alias to `/etc/profile`, but not sure if it works or not.

```
alias = 'node --max-old-space-size=128'
```

Comment: hello, it's been over 3 years but how'd you manage to get it working? or did you? :3 i'm wanting to limit the ram usage too...

Comment: Have you tried using the `--max-heap-size` flag?